# CCTableView in cocos2d Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a simple game in cocos2d android; I want to use a table view for displaying data.

I have Googled and came to know there is a CCTableView in cocos2d but I didn't get the sample code to proceed.

How do I use the CCTableView in cocos2d android?

Answer (score 0):

There is no CCTableView in standard cocos2d (ios or android or cocos2d-x) Framework. It is an extension written by someone else. If you are coding in Java or C++, I guess you have to port the Class by yourself.